# fwrite() doesn't finish writing to file

Tags: c, byte, fwrite, fread

Trying to send a file from client to server.

This is how I receive it:

```
printf("Server receiving file...\n");
while((bytes_read = read(sd, buf, sizeof(buf))) > 0){ //second read now retrieving the file size
  printf("writing");
  fwrite(buf, 1, bytes_read, fp);
  printf("checking if reached here");
}
```

For some reason, the second print statement "checking if reached here" is never reached, and the program just doesn't exit the loop. What could be the issue?

PS. My client sends all the bytes so there is no issue with sending. Its only the writing to the file

Comment: @MikeCAT How can I remove the null bytes, because I just cant find a method over the internet. My sending code is posted. Besides that, would there be an issue in trying to fwrite null bytes to a file?

Comment: @MikeCAT Also I apologize because I've completely changed the context of my question. I would still like to know how I can remove the null bytes before sending though

Comment: Maybe force the output to the screen? Add `fflush(stdout);` after your printf, or, maybe better, terminate the print with a newline: `printf("...\n");`

Comment: Darren, Does "writing" appear?  If not try again with `printf("writing\n");`  (added \n)

Answer (score 1):

Is the socket blocking (the default) ?

If it is, whenever there is no data to read, the read() will hang, waiting for
more data (or for the socket to close, in which case it will return 0 bytes).

Answer (score 0):

Did you open the file using the fopen function?
Here is a small example regarding a piece of code you should have somewhere in your script.

```
fp = fopen( "file", "w" );
```

Check if you have a similar line somewhere, otherwise you will need to add this.

Comment: Yes I did. I opened the file for creation to copy the contents into using this while loop. When I force stop the program, I can see that the file has actually been created but some contents are missing. I'm assuming thats because I've had to force stop it instead of the loop exiting on its own

Comment: Could it be that it wont write correctly because I've included null bytes in the buffer?

Comment: `read()` and `fwrite()` are `'\0'` agnostic, it's just a byte like all the others to them

Comment: @pmg For some reason, my print statement has reached the 'checked if reached here' part even though I didnt change anything, but still doesn't exit the loop afterwards. I think its because my while loop has a wrong condition maybe and is just trying to continue reading even when there is nothing left?

Comment: Maybe the client has to close the connection?

Comment: The client does that when I type in 'quit', something Ive already coded. It just displays the reprompt for me to enter a command (in this case the command that sends a file). But, on the server terminal it never reaches the print statement thats AFTER the while loop, that says the document was received successfully. It just stops at "checking if reached here"